# Memory leak while using text keyed hashtables

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, hashtable

I am writing Bayes naive classifier in Haskell using HashTable package. However when processing bigger corpus i have massive memory leak probably caused by big number of value updates. When loading already specified word counts it takes about 2GB of RAM, but when counting word occurances from corpus 8GB of ram is not enough and it just crashes. How can i prevent it? Code counting words looks like that:

```
chars :: T.Text
chars = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmęóąśłżźćń\t "

el :: Char -> T.Text -> Bool
el = T.any . (==)

preprocess :: T.Text -> [T.Text]
preprocess !line = T.words . T.map check . T.toLower $ line
             where check !x = if x `el` chars then x else ' '

loop :: Handle -> Corpus -> IO ()
loop hdl dic =
    hIsEOF hdl >>= \x -> if x
        then return ()
        else do
          cl:dat <- preprocess <$> TIO.hGetLine hdl
          let ins !word =
                        if (T.length word <= 20) && (T.length word >= 4)
                          then (H.lookup dic word >>=
                                \mprob -> case mprob of
                                   Just (SexProbs m f) -> do
                                     H.delete dic word
                                     H.insert dic word $ if cl == "m" then SexProbs (m+1) f else SexProbs m (f+1)
                                   Nothing -> H.insert dic word $ if cl == "m" then SexProbs 1 0 else SexProbs 0 1)
                          else return ()
          mapM_ ins dat
          loop hdl dic
```

Profiling suggest that the biggest source of allocation are preprocess and loop but i have no idea how to reduce memory usage.

Comment: Can you please list your imports? Which HashTable variant do you use and is Text strict or lazy?

Comment: Also add the definition of `SexProbs` - unless the fields are strict, the `+1` will cause leaks.

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: I am using CuckooHashTable from hashtables packages and strict Text. I omitted strictness annotation in SexProbs fields. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause seems to be your `SexProbs` data type. It is probably defined with lazy fields, i.e. (assuming `Int` for the counters):

```
data SexProbs = SexProbs Int Int
```

Constructing a new value with `SexProbs (m+1) n` will *not* evaluate the addition, but place a thunk in heap memory. These accumulate and cause the space leak.

To avoid this, force evaluation of the counters with `seq`

```
let m' = m+1 in m' `seq` SexProbs m' n
```

or change your type definition to use strict fields:

```
data SexProbs = SexProbs !Int !Int
```